# setCustomValidity error but the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using `setCustomValidity` function to check if the new password and the repeat password are equals but , I debugged the code and the comparisson its correct but the error message its not shown and the form post request its done

```
 <form action="/register" method="post" onsubmit="check_new_password()">
                <div class="form-group">
```

and the javascript

```
 function check_new_password(){
    var new_pass = $('#new-password').val();
    var repeated_pass = $('#repeat-password').val();

    if(new_pass != repeated_pass){
       $('#repeat-password')[0].setCustomValidity('Password are not equals');
    }else{
      $('#repeat-password')[0].setCustomValidity('');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `return` statement in the `onsubmit` attribute, like this:

```
onsubmit="return check_new_password();"
```

So, the `check_new_password()` function needs to return a boolean according the validation.

Don't forget call the `.reportValidity();` method because you're using [**`HTMLObjectElement.setCustomValidity()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity) method.

Additionally, you should add `oninput="setCustomValidity('');"` on the inputs fields to force to update its state.

See in this example:

```js
function check_new_password() {
  var new_pass = $('#new-password').val();
  var repeated_pass = $('#repeat-password').val();

  if (new_pass != repeated_pass) {
    $('#repeat-password')[0].setCustomValidity('Password are not equals.');
    $('#repeat-password')[0].reportValidity();
    return false;
  } else {
    $('#repeat-password')[0].setCustomValidity('');
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="/register" method="post" onsubmit="return check_new_password();">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="new-password">Password:</label>
      <input id="new-password" class="form-control" type="password" oninput="setCustomValidity('');" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="repeat-password">Repeat Password:</label>
      <input id="repeat-password" class="form-control" type="password" oninput="setCustomValidity('');" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```